# Radio button list using Javascript with each list choice returning custom text

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, radio-button

I am making a custom TinyMCE button for Wordpress, part of the Javascript code looks like this:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.Green', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('green', {
                title : 'Prompt Text',
                image : url+'/images/btn_green.jpg',
                onclick : function() {                    
                    var prompt_text = prompt("Green Button", "Green Button Text");
                    var caret = "caret_pos_holder";
                    var insert = "<div>" + prompt_text + "</div><span id="+caret+"></span>";
                    if (prompt_text != null && prompt_text != 'undefined')
                    {
                        ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, insert);
                        ed.selection.select(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //select the span
                        ed.dom.remove(ed.dom.select('span#caret_pos_holder')[0]); //remove the span
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('green', tinymce.plugins.Green);
})();
```

I want to remove the prompt_text function and add a radio button list where a window appears and the user can select one of the options in the list. And each list item should have their unique `insert`. **How is this possible?**

For instance, the window should have a list of three options: *Tea, Coffee, Water*.

If the user selects Coffee, it should insert the text: `Coffee wakes you up`.

My knowledge of Javascript is very limited which is stopping me from solving this. However, I would presume that this is only possible by creating a jQuery form?

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to write an own plugin.
You should take a look at the developer tinymce build and have a look at the source code, especially the searchreplace plugin. This plugin uses a tinymce popup and the user is able to select several settings. I suggest you copy that plugin, adjust it to your needs and remove all the stuff you don't need.